# Sending DTMF after calling a number on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to handle the classic problem of sending DTMF notes after calling a certain number through `PhoneCallTask` in WP7.

Does anyone know the trick to do so? Does the SDK support RFC-2806?

Answer (score 1):

Your app does not have access to the phone call input/output audio and is also deactivated for the duration of the phone call in the platform's current state.